# Filter array of objects from nested array and nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have the following array of object

```
const skus = [
    {
      id: 1,
      features: ["Slim"],
      fields: [
        { label: "Material", value: "Material1" },
        { label: "Type", value: "Type1" }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      features: ["Cotton"],
      fields: [
        { label: "Material", value: "Material2" },
        { label: "Type", value: "Type2" }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      features: ["Slim"],
      fields: [
        { label: "Material", value: "Material3" },
        { label: "Type", value: "Type1" }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

And i want the expected output to be

```
const output = [
    { label: "features", value: ["Slim", "Cotton"] },
    { label: "Material", value: ["Material1", "Material2", "Material3"] },
    { label: "Type", value: ["Type1", "Type2"] }
  ]
```

I tried the following way

```
const output = [];

  let featureArr = [];
  let fieldsArr = []
  skus.forEach(e => {
    e.features.forEach(f => {
      featureArr.push(f);
    });
    e.fields.forEach(f => {
      fieldsArr.push({ label: f.label, value: f.value });
    });
  });
  featureArr = _.uniq(featureArr);
  fieldsArr = _.uniqBy(fieldsArr, 'value')
  fieldsArr = _.groupBy(fieldsArr, 'label');

  output.push({ label: 'Features', value: featureArr })

  for (const k in fieldsArr) {
    let valArr = []
    valArr = fieldsArr[k].map(v => v.value)
    output.push({ label: k, value: valArr });
  }
```

I'm getting the expected output, but here multiple loops are present. Is there a way on how can i write the solution in more optimized way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Build an object with values as `Sets`. Then convert the object of sets into array of array.

```js
const skus = [
  {
    id: 1,
    features: ["Slim"],
    fields: [
      { label: "Material", value: "Material1" },
      { label: "Type", value: "Type1" }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    features: ["Cotton"],
    fields: [
      { label: "Material", value: "Material2" },
      { label: "Type", value: "Type2" }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    features: ["Slim"],
    fields: [
      { label: "Material", value: "Material3" },
      { label: "Type", value: "Type1" }
    ]
  }
];

const update = data => {
  const res = {};
  data.forEach(item => {
    const features = res["features"] || new Set();
    item.features.forEach(fea => features.add(fea));
    res["features"] = features;

    item.fields.forEach(field => {
      const labels = res[field.label] || new Set();
      labels.add(field.value);
      res[field.label] = labels;
    });
  });
  return Object.keys(res).map(key => ({ label: key, value: [...res[key]] }));
};

console.log(update(skus));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a grouping function for nested properties, where a map, an array for iterating, group and value keys are handed over. The result is a map with all collected values for each group.

Later get all unique values from the map and build a new array of objects.

```js
const
    skus = [{ id: 1, features: ["Slim"], fields: [{ label: "Material", value: "Material1" }, { label: "Type", value: "Type1" }] }, { id: 2, features: ["Cotton"], fields: [{ label: "Material", value: "Material2" }, { label: "Type", value: "Type2" }] }, { id: 3, features: ["Slim"], fields: [{ label: "Material", value: "Material3" }, { label: "Type", value: "Type1" }] }],
    getGrouped = (map, array, key, value) => array.reduce((m, o) =>
        m.set(o[key], [...(m.get(o[key]) || []), o[value]]), map),
    result = Array.from(
        skus.reduce((m, o) =>
            getGrouped(
                m.set('features', [...(m.get('features') || []), ...o.features]),
                o.fields,
                'label',
                'value'
            ),
            new Map
        ),
        ([label, value]) => ({ label, value: [...new Set(value)] })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use them, [Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) will be your friend here:

```js
//data
const skus = [{id: 1,features: ["Slim"],fields: [{ label: "Material", value: "Material1" },{ label: "Type", value: "Type1" }]},{id: 2,features: ["Cotton"],fields: [{ label: "Material", value: "Material2" },{ label: "Type", value: "Type2" }]},{id: 3,features: ["Slim"],fields: [{ label: "Material", value: "Material3" },{ label: "Type", value: "Type1" }]}];

//solution
const output = Object.entries(skus.reduce((map,sku) => {
  sku.features.forEach(feat => map.features.add(feat));
  sku.fields.forEach(field => (map[field.label] = (map[field.label] || new Set()).add(field.value)));
  return map;
}, {features: new Set()})).map(([label, set]) => ({label, value: Array.from(set)}));

//display
console.log(output);
```

Each feature array and field array only get iterated exactly once using this approach.

If you can't use Sets, you can emulate their behavior using js objects. The goal is to use some structure that doesn't need to be iterated again to find unique values.

Answer (score 0):

The following function will do the job

```
const fn = (array) => {
  return array.reduce((result, element) => {
    const features = result[0].value
    const feature = element.features[0]
    if (!features.includes(feature)) {
      features.push(feature)
    }
    const materials = result[1].value
    const material = element.fields[0].value
    if (!materials.includes(material)) {
      materials.push(material)
    }
    const types = result[2].value
    const type = element.fields[1].value
    if (!types.includes(type)) {
      types.push(type)
    }
    return result
  }, [
    { label: 'features', value: [] },
    { label: 'Material', value: [] },
    { label: 'Type', value: [] }
  ])
}
```

BUT, your object structure is quite messy, you should likely build accessor functions that extract information from your initial elements, and use some helper functions to populate your result object.
Anyway, read more about the 'reduce' function used here ;)
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce